# Is there a way to automatically detect strings that are not localized?

Tags: web-applications, localization, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

In our web application, we are using i18-next for internationalization. All the texts that has to be displayed in UI, needs to be localized like t("clickMe"). Sometimes there are chances that team members can miss out to do the localization (Instead of localizing the string using a key in .json file, leaving the string as it is). Is there a way to avoid this? So that we can make sure all the strings in the applications are localised? Is there any automatic approaches to identify this instead of manual findings?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries like [i18next-parser](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser) and [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner) or the [saveMissing feature](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#missing-keys) of i18next, like in [this example](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/2bd69a2cc638acfafb37dc0c56db6add4e9dac85/example/locize/src/i18n.js#L49)